# When publishing solution, is it possible to ignore certain projects?

Tags: msbuild, publish-profiles

We have some projects that are only used in some environments so I would like publishing to skip them.  However, when publishing the whole solution I get the following msbuild error:

```
"C:\Source\Solution.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Source\Project\Project.csproj" (default target) (51) ->
(ValidatePublishProfileSettings target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4253,5): error : The value for PublishProfile is set to 'Sta
ge', expected to find the file at 'C:\Source\Project\Properties\PublishProfiles\Stage.pubxml' but it could not be found. [C:\Source\Project\Project.csproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4260,4): error : PublishProfile(Stage) is set. But the $(Web
PublishMethod) does not have a valid value.  Current Value is "". [C:\Source\Project\Project.csproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4267,5): error : Target ValidatePublishProfileSettings Faile
d [C:\Source\Project\Project.csproj]
```

Is there any way to ignore the project when publishing the solution so I don't get build errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with:

1. a custom build srcript (call msbuild individually for every *project* that you want to publish) (my preferred option hence it gives you much more flexibility)
2. a custom .sln file with only needed projects for the sole purpose of publishing (easier option, but harder to maintain)

   3.Just a wild guess(never tried this for deployment, but should work based on my understanding) - you could try using `Build -> Configuration Manager` dialog in VS to uncheck *build* checkboxes for certain projects if you can go with creating separate solution configurations for separate deployment plans:
   [image: configuration manager]

Comment: I tried building an individual project but then it complains about missing project references which presumably the solution normally takes care of.  A custom solution seems like double work.  One of the nice things about publish profiles is that [in theory] you can get rid of environment-specific build configs.  While your idea works, it means you have to copy your Release web.config transforms to the build-specific config.  I'm honestly leaning toward publishing to a folder that's ignored since they're the exception unless a better solution comes up.

Comment: did you add references to projects or files? msbuild usually handles project references correctly when building a .csproj/.vbproj file. (but obviously, it has no ability to handle file references)

Comment: We have references to both projects and files.  Either way, we have console applications and those don't use publish profiles so I have to use the environment-specific build configs anyway.  In that case I can just uncheck build for that project.